# Eliminate rows in a Pandas dataframe on complex condition

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with some columns and 221 rows. Let's say the columns of interest are `'col1'` and `'col2'`. `'col1'` has all strings, while `'col2'` is all integers. Now I want to eliminate rows where `'col1' == 'A' & 'col2' == 1`.

It is rather easy to get a boolean vector with `True` corresponding to all rows that meet the condition. In order to delete them, I thought if I could invert the boolean vector (have `False` where the the condition is met), I can just index my DataFrame with the inverted vector and be done.

In the process I have, I think made an interesting discovery: List comprehension is faster than numpy invert method for a boolean vector. The length of the vector in question is 221. Here is what I did:

```
In  [1]: def npinvert():
             return np.invert((df['col1'] == 'A') & (df['col2'] == 1))
         def licomp():
             return [not i for i in ((df['col1'] == 'A') & (df['col2'] == 1))]
```

And then:

```
In  [2]: %timeit npinvert()
Out [2]: 1000 loops, best of 3: 902 µs per loop

In  [3]: %timeit licomp()
Out [3]: 1000 loops, best of 3: 880 µs per loop
```

In any case, I get what I want. But, is there an even faster way to do this? I will have to run this on a much larger DataFrame in the near future. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To really compare these you need to test them on a range of sizes. Add any test functions you can think of to see if you can improve on the pandas method of `~ (conditions)`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Big (100,000 rows) test dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(1, 10, 100000),
                   'b': [np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C']) for i in range(100000)]})

def check_pandas(df):
    return ~ ((df['a'] == 1) & (df['b'] == 'A'))

def check_list(df):
    return [not i for i in ((df['b'] == 'A') & (df['a'] == 1))]

def check_numpy(df):
   return np.invert((df['a'] == 1) & (df['b'] == 'A'))

sizes = []
pandas_times = []
list_times = []
np_times = []

for df_size in range(1, 100001, 1000):
    sizes.append(df_size)

    current_df = df.iloc[:df_size, :]
    pandas_before = time.time()
    check_pandas(current_df)
    pandas_after = time.time()
    pandas_times.append(float(pandas_after - pandas_before))

    before = time.time()
    check_list(current_df)
    after = time.time()
    list_times.append(float(after - before))

    before = time.time()
    check_numpy(current_df)
    after = time.time()
    np_times.append(float(after - before))


# Plot results
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(sizes, pandas_times, 'ro', label='pandas')
ax.plot(sizes, list_times, 'bs', label='list')
ax.plot(sizes, np_times, 'g+', label='numpy')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
```

[image: Timing results]

Once the dataframe gets pretty large, using the vectorized
`pandas` `~` and `numpy.invert` to invert the boolean seems to be much faster.

Comment: Also, the list comprehension produces a list (duh) and the others return an array or series.  Assuming a series is desired, that's a small extra amount of time to convert a list to a series.  But in the bigger picture, these boolean operations are not really vectorized *math* operations so I don't think we'd expect to see much speed up compared to, say, using a list comprehension to add 9 to every element of a list vs doing the same thing in numpy (which is basically what the results show).